# set explicit source update while using data context

Tags: wpf

I need to update the binding source object with the control values only during a button click event.

But as my top level has datacontext being set, it's updating the source object whenever the control values change... Is it possible to set explicitly to update it during that event only keeping the datacontext as it is?

Comment: If i understand you correctly, you want a textbox bound to a property to only update the prop when a button is clicked? This isn't really data-binding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TextBox binding:

```
<TextBox x:Name="myTextBox" Text="{Binding MyTextProperty, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"/>
```

Button handler code:

```
myTextBox.GetBindingExpression(TextBox.TextProperty).UpdateSource();
```